# Loops in Makefile

Tags: refactoring, makefile

I have a lot of assignments where I have to continually update a Makefile as I add more subsequently numbered C programs.  Is there a way to do this with a loop which iterates over the values 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc.?

```
all: 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7. 1.8 1.9

1.1: 1.1.o
    gcc -o 1.1 $(FLAGS) 1.1.o
1.1.o: 1.1.c
    gcc -c $(FLAGS) 1.1.c

1.2: 1.2.o
    gcc -o 1.2 $(FLAGS) 1.2.o
1.2.o: 1.2.c
    gcc -c $(FLAGS) 1.2.c

1.3: 1.3.o
    gcc -o 1.3 $(FLAGS) 1.3.o
1.3.o: 1.3.c
    gcc -c $(FLAGS) 1.3.c

1.4: 1.4.o
    gcc -o 1.4 $(FLAGS) 1.4.o
1.4.o: 1.4.c
    gcc -c $(FLAGS) 1.4.c

1.5: 1.5.o
    gcc -o 1.5 $(FLAGS) 1.5.o
1.5.o: 1.5.c
    gcc -c $(FLAGS) 1.5.c

1.6: 1.6.o
    gcc -o 1.6 $(FLAGS) 1.6.o
1.6.o: 1.6.c
    gcc -c $(FLAGS) 1.6.c

1.7: 1.7.o
    gcc -o 1.7 $(FLAGS) 1.7.o
1.7.o: 1.7.c
    gcc -c $(FLAGS) 1.7.c

1.8: 1.8.o
    gcc -o 1.8 $(FLAGS) 1.8.o
1.8.o: 1.8.c
    gcc -c $(FLAGS) 1.8.c

1.9: 1.9.o
    gcc -o 1.9 $(FLAGS) 1.9.o
1.9.o: 1.9.c
    gcc -c $(FLAGS) 1.9.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7. 1.8 1.9
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want a [suffix rule](http://owen.sj.ca.us/rkowen/howto/slides/make/slides/makesuff.html), not a loop.

Comment: Good call -- a suffix rule will eliminate duplication of the build rules.  Combined with a loop that specifies the dependencies, we've covered scalability as well!

Comment: No, he (or at least the world in general) does not necessarily want a suffix rule.  He may want to create rules to built 1.1 from 1.1.o, and so on to 1.8<-1.8.o, but he may NOT want to create 1.9 from 1.9.o - perhaps he wants FOOBAR to be built from 1.9.o.  Or perhaps 1.9 is built from SPECIAL.1.9.o,  and 1.9.o goes somewhere else entirely. //  He may want to have a suffix rule, that only applies to a specified list of files with that suffix, and not all files with that suffix.

Answer (score 2):

Try a rule like:

```
OBJECTS = 1.1.o 1.2.o 1.3.o

all: $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.c
    gcc $(FLAGS) %< -o $*
```

Then you just need to add the extra object to the list and all is sweet.

Implicit rules help you really minimise the copy/paste cycle in your makefile.

http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/make/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you can use shell commands in a Makefile, and make itself may offer the looping you need.  There are oodles of good examples all over the web; assuming from your use of `gcc` that you're also using GNU make, try here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function